# How to link different slideshow images with a URL in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am very new to JavaScript and I am creating a simple slideshow and I got it work ok. The only thing is I can't seem to create a web link to each of the images in my slideshow.  I would like for it to link to a different web page to the 4 different images I have for the slideshow as it scrolls though.

Here is what I have:

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
//preload images
var image1=new Image()
image1.src="Images/slideshow_1_home_2013.jpg"
var image2=new Image()
image2.src="Images/slideshow_2_home_2013.jpg"
var image3=new Image()
image3.src="Images/slideshow_3_home_2013.jpg"
var image4=new Image()
image4.src="Images/slideshow_4_home_2013.jpg"
//-->
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div align="left"><img src="Images/slideshow_1_home_2013.jpg" 
 name="slide" width="974"  height="305" align="left"/></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
var step=1
var whichimage=1
function slideit(){
if (!document.images)
return
document.images.slide.src=eval("image"+step+".src")
whichimage=step
if (step<4)
step++
else
step=1
setTimeout("slideit()",10000)
}
slideit()
function slidelink(){
if (whichimage==1)
window.location="link1.htm"
else if (whichimage==2)
window.location="link2.htm"
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It would be helpful if your Javascript was well-formatted, and in a useable state.  As posted, you don't even have the semi-colons in your code.

Comment: I agree.  Being the expert, how would you do it?

Answer (score 1):

One way is to use a link to wrap up your images:

```
    <head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        <!--
//preload images
var image1=new Image()
image1.src="Images/slideshow_1_home_2013.jpg"
var image2=new Image()
image2.src="Images/slideshow_2_home_2013.jpg"
var image3=new Image()
image3.src="Images/slideshow_3_home_2013.jpg"
var image4=new Image()
image4.src="Images/slideshow_4_home_2013.jpg"
//-->
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div align="left"><a name="mylink" href=""><img src="Images/slideshow_1_home_2013.jpg" 
        name="slide" width="974"  height="305" align="left"/></a></div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            <!--
            var step=1
            var whichimage=1
            function slideit(){
                if (!document.images)
                    return
                document.images.slide.src=eval("image"+step+".src")

                whichimage=step
                if (step<4)
                    step++
                else
                    step=1
                setTimeout("slideit()",10000)
            }
            slideit();

            if (whichimage==1)
                document.links.mylink.src="link1.htm"
            else if (whichimage==2)
                document.links.mylink.src="link2.htm"

        </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Hi-thank you for your response...is there a way to link each one of the images to a different URL link each time as it scrolls through each different image?

Comment: absolutely. you can create a simple array with the links and every time it slides, choose the next element in the array

Answer (score 0):

### There is an easier ways to do that:
first:create an HTML document and we are going to call it images.html
in that file just add all the images you want to load
like:

```
<img src="img1.jpg" onload="parent.loadedimg()" />
<img src="img2.jpg" onload="parent.loadedimg()" />
<img src="img3.jpg" onload="parent.loadedimg()" />
```

we use parent to call a function from our iframe to our index.html file
then just add to your page index.html this anywhere you want it wont affect your page

```
<div style="display:none>
<iframe src="images.html">
</iframe>
</div>
```

so now the images will start loading automatically.
now add this HTML anywhere you want your image to be displayed

```
<img src="img1.jpg" width="400" height="300" id="slider" />
```

finally the Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
startslide();
var imgnum=parseInt;
imgnum=0;
maximg=parseInt;
maximg=0;

function loadedimg(){
maximg++;
}

function startslide(){
if(imgnum&lt;=maximg && maximg>0){
imgnum++;
document.getElementById('slider').src='img'+imgnum+'.jpg';
if(imgnum==maximg){
imgnum=0;
}
}
window.setTimeout(function(){startslide()},2000);
}
</script>
```

now explanation:
if you remember in the iframe every time that an image load sends a function to the javascript in this javascript when the function is called the var maximg change by 1 so every time an image load this var sum up 1 in this example when all the images finish to load the final number for maximg is going to be 3 cause in the iframe you only loaded 3 images, and now you don't need to worry for the ammount of the images you want to load you just add so many images as you want in the iframe.
the var imgnum it is used to change the src of the image to be displayed, so be sure that al your images have the same name, and then the number of the order to be displayed.
and the line that used window.setTimeout will define how much time will wait to change to the next image in this case i use 2000 and it means 2 seconds, 500 means 0.5 seconds,5000 means 5 seconds, so change it to any number you want to wait.
that it's all so i hope been helpful for you!.

Comment: Hi! Thank you for taking the time to help out a beginner who is totally lost.  Where would I add the /div?  To a css file or within the body?

Comment: well there are many ways to add a css to a div you could use in the div this, <div style="border-radius:5px; width:400px; height:300px; box-shadow:0px 0px 10px #000000">Your Content here</div>, or adding between the head this <style type="text/css"> .mystyle{color:#888888; font-size:36px;}</style>and the HTML would be <div class="mystyle">my content</div> the class name in the HTML if defined on how you name it between the style tag, and the other way is create a .css external file with all the css rules, and adding on your HTML index.html <lin rel="stylesheet" href="nameile.css" />that is all